# Woher kommt die Redewendung 'Sich an die eigene Nase fassen'?

Tags: idiom

Ich habe diese Redewendung kürzlich gehört und frage mich, wieso man das so sagt. Woher kommt diese Redewendung?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Die Redensart geht vermutlich auf eine normannische Rechtsgebärde zurück. Ein Verleumder, der zum Widerruf verurteilt wurde, musste sich während der Widerrufungsformel an die eigene Nase fassen. Die Wandlung zur Redensart geht wahrscheinlich auf populäre Bilderbögen der Barockzeit zurück ([Quelle](http://www.redensarten-index.de/mobil/#suchbegriff=sich+an+die+eigene+Nase+fassen&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou))

[Hier](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_deutscher_Redewendungen#/media/Datei%3AUrach_Prunkschlitten_20c.jpg) eine bildhafte Darstellung der Redensart als Detail eines barocken Prunkschlittens.

Comment: Merkwürdig, *sich an die Nase fassen* impliziert ja schon die eigene Nase. Die nochmalige Betonung lässt es klingen, als habe man jmd. anderem an die Nase gefasst, aber dafür liefert Erklärung keine Entsprechung. Ob das Zeigen mit dem Finger in die Mitte des Gesichts eines Anderen hier das Äquivalent wäre und auch der Grund für diesen Brauch?

Comment: Ich kann mir vorstellen, dass das eventuell daher rührt, dass man, wenn man jemanden beschuldigt impliziert, dass die Person sich an die Nase fassen müsste. Die Antwort des Beschuldigten könnte dann sein "Da musst Du Dich an Deine eigene Nase fassen!".

Comment: Und trau' dich bloss nicht, *dich an meine Nase zu fassen* (???)